Selecting the "Other" option when voting to close a question as off-topic in staging ground inserts suboptimal text
This is a minor bug for sure, but it should also be very easy to fix. In Staging Ground, when voting to close as off-topic, there are some canned choices and lastly an "Other" choice that allows the reviewer to enter a custom close reason. This generates a partially filled-in comment that says

I think that this topic is off-topic because

I believe it should say

I think that this question is off-topic because

In other words, replace the first "topic" with "question".
A little image to give more context


Note: This was changed during the beta to avoid the term "closing". beta team link Also questioned during the beta here in chat (including this exact point). (Both links are internal to people participating in the SG betas)

Why avoid calling things what they are, in favor of calling them what they aren't?

Changing the first word to question doesn't impact the use of the term "off topic"

While we're at it, the "I think that this [...]" wording is arguably a bit weak. In all other templates, the wording is direct, and doesn't imply anything subjective - including in the other off-topic close reasons in the SG. Here's the resource recommendation close comment for comparison: "Off-topic reason: This question is seeking recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources. It does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines. [link omitted because reasons]"
